# WSO2 API Manager Async APIs support

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, asyncapi

Is it possible in WSO2 API Manager, or maybe is it on the roadmap, to publish an async API, for example in Kafka, and manage it like other sync API with spec (Async API spec), security, analytics, etc?

I am not referring to websocket APIs, that I know it is already supported in WSO2 AM. It is event based asynchronous APIs.

I could not find any clear info about it onto wso2 website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async APIs support will be available in WSO2 APIM 4.0 which is planned to be released on Q1 2021.

Comment: But Q1 2020 already passed, and the last version of APIM is 3.2. You maybe mean Q1 2021? Is there any public info from wso2 for this? I mean to know what this new feature includes

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 2021. We don't have anything public about this feature yet, because it's still in the planning stage. However, we will have something soon.

Comment: More details: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9632

Answer (score 2):

Async API support is now released for WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0. It can be checked in the overview and about of the release officialy published a days ago.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/get-started/about-this-release/